# Querying a collection of documents in firestore and saving it in a variable always return empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I've been trying to query a collection in firestore to return documents that meets a certain condition and saving the result in a variable as follows:

```
exports.getFriendsScreams = (req, res) => {
    const user = req.user.handle;
    let friendsList = [];
    let friendsPost = [];
    db.collection("users")
        .doc(user)
        .get()
        .then(snap => {
            friendsList = snap.data().friends;
            friendsList.forEach(friend => {
                db.collection("screams")
                    .where("handle", "==", friend)
                    .orderBy("createdAt", "desc")
                    .get()
                    .then(snapshot => {
                        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                            friendsPost.push(doc.data());
                        });
                    });
            });
            return res.status(201).json({ friendsPost });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            return res.status(500).json({error: err.message});
        });
};
```

but the data returned to the client in **res.json** which is **friendsPost** always returns empty but when I log the value of **friendsPost** to the console within the second for each block it returns the correct value but outside the block it returns empty, I would like to know what I am doing wrong please.

Comment: Firestore queries (and anything that returns a promise) are asynchronous and return immediately before the work is complete.  Your code is not waiting for the inner queries to complete before sending the response.  The response is being sent immediately with an empty array.  You will have to add code to make sure the queries complete first.

Comment: @DougStevenson I didn't take note of that thanks I'll go try it